# How can show error.ftl page in keycloak theme built by Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, keycloak

I have used Vue 3 and vuetify with webpack.config for buidling keycloak theme. When user enters asn invalid url, I expect that error page rendered, but the following error appears:

> Internal Server Error , Error id 9b20c47f-d0d6-4b7d-ab92-1f107c5b5c9e-45

I also have defined my template.ftl as follows:

```
<#macro registrationLayout bodyClass="" displayInfo=false displayMessage=true displayRequiredFields=false showAnotherWayIfPresent=true>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="${properties.kcHtmlClass!}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="${url.resourcesPath}/img/kando.ico" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link href='${url.resourcesPath}/css/index.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    
      <#nested "styles">
       
    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script id="environment" type="application/json">


    {
  
      "urls": {
        "project":"${url.resourcesPath}",
        "loginResetCredentials": "${url.loginResetCredentialsUrl}",
        "login": "${url.loginUrl}",
        "registration": "${url.registrationUrl}",
        "loginAction": "${url.loginAction}",
        "registrationAction": "${url.registrationAction}",
        "loginRestartFlowUrl":"${url.loginRestartFlowUrl}"
      },
      "titles": {
        "loginProfileTitle": "${msg("loginProfileTitle")}",
        "loginAccountTitle": "${msg("loginAccountTitle")}",
        "registerTitle": "${msg("registerTitle")}",
        "emailForgotTitle": "${msg("emailForgotTitle")}",
        "confirmLinkIdpTitle": "${msg("confirmLinkIdpTitle")}",
        "emailLinkIdpTitle": "${msg("emailLinkIdpTitle", idpDisplayName)}"
      },
      "permissions": {
        "usernameEditDisabled": <#if usernameEditDisabled??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "loginWithEmailAllowed": <#if realm.loginWithEmailAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationEmailAsUsername": <#if realm.registrationEmailAsUsername>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "rememberMe": <#if realm.rememberMe>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "resetPasswordAllowed": <#if realm.resetPasswordAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "password": <#if realm.password>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationAllowed": <#if realm.registrationAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationDisabled": <#if registrationDisabled??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "passwordRequired": <#if passwordRequired??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "phoneNumberIsRequired": <#if phoneNumberRequired??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "verifyPhoneIsRequired":  <#if verifyPhone??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "supportPhone": <#if supportPhone??>true<#else>false</#if>
       
      },
      "error":{
        "errorCondition": <#if !(auth?has_content && auth.showUsername() && !auth.showResetCredentials())>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "requiredField": <#if displayRequiredFields>true<#else>false</#if>
      },
      "labels": {
        "firstName": "${msg("firstName")}",
        "lastName": "${msg("lastName")}",
        "username": "${msg("username")}",
        "usernameOrEmail": "${msg("usernameOrEmail")}",
        "email": "${msg("email")}",
        "password": "${msg("password")}",
        "passwordConfirm": "${msg("passwordConfirm")}",
        "rememberMe": "${msg("rememberMe")}",
        "doForgotPassword": "${msg("doForgotPassword")}",
        "doLogIn": "${msg("doLogIn")}",
        "doSubmit": "${msg("doSubmit")}",
        "noAccount": "${msg("noAccount")}",
        "doRegister": "${msg("doRegister")}",
        "backToLogin": "${kcSanitize(msg("backToLogin"))?no_esc}",
        "confirmLinkIdpContinue": "${msg("confirmLinkIdpContinue")}",
        "doClickHere": "${msg("doClickHere")}"
      },

      "totp":{
        "totpTopSecret": <#if totp??>"${(totp.totpSecret!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "totpQrCode": <#if totp??>"${(totp.totpSecretQrCode)}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "totpError": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('totp')>true<#else>false</#if>
      },
      "forms": {
        "loginUsername": "${(login.username!'')}",
        "loginRememberMe": <#if login.rememberMe??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "selectedCredential": "${(auth.selectedCredential!'')}",
        "registerFirstName": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.firstName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerLastName": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.lastName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerEmail": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.email!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerUsername": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.username!'')}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "user": {
        "username": <#if user??>"${(user.username!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "email": <#if user??>"${(user.email!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "firstName": <#if user??>"${(user.firstName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "lastName": <#if user??>"${(user.lastName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "validations": {
        "firstName": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('firstName')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('firstName'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "lastName":  <#if messagesPerField.existsError('lastName')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('lastName'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "email": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('email')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('email'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "usernameOrPassword": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('username','password')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.getFirstError('username','password'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "username": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('username')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('username'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "password": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "passwordConfirm": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password-confirm')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password-confirm'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "PhoneOrCode": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('code','phoneNumber')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.getFirstError('phoneNumber','code'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "RegisterCode": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('registerCode')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('registerCode'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>    
      },
      "message": {
        "type": <#if displayMessage && message?has_content && (message.type != 'warning' || !isAppInitiatedAction??)>"${message.type}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "summary": <#if displayMessage && message?has_content && (message.type != 'warning' || !isAppInitiatedAction??)>"${kcSanitize(message.summary)?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "instruction": {
        "title": "${msg("appRealmName",realm.displayName)}",
         "realmTitle":"${msg("realName",realm.name)}",
        "emailLinkIdp1": "${msg("emailLinkIdp1", idpDisplayName, realm.username, realm.displayName)}",
        "emailLinkIdp2": "${msg("emailLinkIdp2")}",
        "emailLinkIdp3": "${msg("emailLinkIdp3")}",
        "emailLinkIdp4": "${msg("emailLinkIdp4")}",
        "emailLinkIdp5": "${msg("emailLinkIdp5")}"
      },
      "social": [
        <#if realm.password && social.providers??>
          <#list social.providers as p>
            { 
              "alias": "${p.alias}",
              "displayName": "${p.displayName!}",
              "loginUrl": "${p.loginUrl}"
            }<#sep>, </#sep>
          </#list>
        </#if>
      ]
    }
  </script>
 <#nested "scripts">
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

and each page built by webpack.config as the following structure:
for example my error.ftl page:

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout; section>
     <#if section = "scripts">
        <script typo="module" src="${url.resourcesPath}/js/error.js"></script>

    </#if>
</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

and I should say that, the error.js and all other pages, is the output build file of my Vue project.
All pages are rendered correclty, but when i enter a invalid url in browser, the error page mus tbe shown, but the mentioned problem appears!.
How can handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, at some pages such as error page, some keycloak context variables are null and they should be handled in template.ftl at script json. for this purpose, I have added the following condition:

```
<#if auth.hasContent>
  <script type='application/json' id='environment'>
    ....
  </script>

<#else>
   <script type='application/json' id='environment>
     ... some variables with valid value
  </script>

</#if>
```